# How to convert an integer in a base to a string

Tags: ruby

Sometimes I have integers like these `021` or `011`.

If I try to convert them to a string, the result will be:

```
p 021.to_s # "17" instead "021"
p 011.to_s # "9" instead "011"
```

Why does this happen and how can I convert the integers to strings?

Comment: `021` is an octal integer literal, and its value is `17`, that's why when you invoke to_s on it, you get `"17"` - its value as a string.

Comment: You can use `to_s(8)` but you'll lose the first 0.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what *precisely* is unclear to you about [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers). That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't fall into the same trap. Make the world a better place!

Comment: @JörgWMittag Possibly the problem with the documentation is that it was unread. Making it read will help.

Comment: @theTinMan: In that case, the question is similar: why wasn't the OP able to find the documentation and what can be improved to make the documentation easier to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric literals with a leading zero are considered to be octal (base 8) numbers.

The `to_s` method converts the numbers to the default decimal (base 10).

- 21 octal is 17 decimal
- 11 octal is 9 decimal

For the expected results, remove the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the [literals](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers) documentation to find the special prefixs to write numbers in decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary formats.

> For decimal numbers use a prefix of 0d, for hexadecimal numbers use a prefix of 0x, for octal numbers use a prefix of 0 or 0o, for binary numbers use a prefix of 0b. The alphabetic component of the number is not case-sensitive.

`21` or `0d21` is considered as number in decimal format but `021` is considered as number in octal format. And when interpreted to print it, it uses default decimal format.